# Append Vue Components to the DOM

Tags: vue.js

I would like to dynamically append Vue Components to a container.

I have a `Dashboard.vue` like this:

```
<template>
   <div id="container"></div>
</template>
```

Then I have 3 components: `LineChart.vue , Bar.vue , Cake.vue`

I will be fetching data from a database depending on what users want to search, and everytime they make a query, I want to append one of the 3 components into `"container"`

So for example if a user makes 4 querys, generating 2 LineCharts, 1 Bar and 1 Cake, I want the `Dashboard.vue` to look like this:

```
<template>
   <div id="container">
      <LineChart id="lineChart1"></LineChart>
      <LineChart id="lineChart2"></LineChart>
      <Bar id="bar1"></Bar>
      <Cake id="cake1"></Cake>
   </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use vuejs dynamic components.
Let's say that your backend returns this result, where component is the name of your vue component :

```js
items = [
     {component:"LineChart", ...},
     {component:"LineChart", ...},
     {component:"Bar", ...},
     {component:"Cake", ...},
]
```

Your html template should look like :

```html
<template>
   <div id="container">
      <template v-for="(item,index) in items" >
          <component :key="index" :is="item.component" :id="`${item.component}${index}`"></component>
      </template>
   </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of for this is to make a `v-for` for each component.

You will have something like this:

```html
<template>
 <LineChart v-for="i in lineCount" :key="'line'+i" />
 <Bar v-for="i in barCount" :key="'bar'+i" />
 <Cake v-for="i in cakeCount" :key="'cake'+i" />
</template>
```

However, I am really sure though, there is a better approach for this.